# How fill the polygon in boost?

Tags: c++, boost, polygon, triangulation, boost-geometry

I have code like this:

> typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon< Point2, false > Polygon;
>
> Polygon boundary;

And I need to fill boundary. I think that it must be very easy, bur I've never used boost, and I have not found instruction for this. I looked into many examples, but they didn't contain needed actions.
I try use project umeshu https://github.com/vladimir-ch/umeshu/ for create grid with good triangulation. And I just need to understand how to fill initial data.

Answer (score 3):

The interface you want is:

```
//! This refers to the exterior ring of the polygon.
inline ring_type& outer() { return m_outer; }

//! This refers to a collection of rings which are holes inside the polygon.
inline inner_container_type & inners() { return m_inners; }
```

By default ring_type is a std::vector where Point is a template parameter you specify (Point2 in your case.)

Try:

```
boundary.outer().push_back(Point2(x, y)); //This fills the exterior boundary with one point whose coordinates are x and y.
```

Here is a fully working example:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

int main(void)
{
    typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
    typedef bg::model::polygon<point> polygon;

    //! create a polygon
    polygon p;
    p.outer().push_back(point(0., 0.));
    p.outer().push_back(point(1., 0.));
    p.outer().push_back(point(1., 2.));
    p.outer().push_back(point(2., 3.));
    p.outer().push_back(point(0., 4.));

    //! display it
    std::cout << "generated polygon:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << bg::wkt<polygon>(p) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
generated polygon:
POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 2,2 3,0 4))
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I've got run-time error by this way((

Comment: boundary.outer().resize(100); - this code bring out run-time error too.

Comment: Thank you, it works... and I don't know how.. but my code too. I just come to work today and run my application. I think cause of problem was in my libraries. Yesterday I've installed a lot of different applications, which contain many libraries and boost too. May be in boost were some problems.